# Can I meet the Grox or get to the center of the galaxy without antagonizing anybody?

Tags: spore

The Grox are remarkably unpleasant, and will hound you on your way to the galactic core and back, and then possibly go into a nearly-infinite war with you, being extremely hard to eradicate at 2400 planets. I would like to meet them. I also would like to not have to drop whatever I'm doing to defend a colony against a Grox attack every 5 minutes afterward.

Can I balance my relationship with the Grox so that they will never attack me, but without allying with them and making the rest of the galaxy attack me or having to travel all the way back to the center of the galaxy again and again to shine my happy ray on them? Failing that, can I reach the galactic core without them becoming aware of my existence, eliminating the problem in an unsatisfying way?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, it won't be possible without having a fight with the Grox or with every single other race. They will also be aware of your existence, but there is a little workaround.

It is actually possible to get there without a fight, but it's considered 'cheating'  by a large playerbase. This is how it works:

The `p` button pauses the game and allows you to plot a 
course without having to rush or panic. You can actually hit `pause` when you are almost at the target planet, and then select an other planet. When you get to the Grox, continue along, but, continually 
press the `p` key to pause the game so that you never actually land on a star 
system before moving to the next. This might result in the Grox never hitting you.

If you don't want to do it like this, then it's strongly recommended that you not start out at war with anyone when you begin your quest to locate the Galactic Core.  If you are not at war with anyone, whenever you get attacked, it will only be by generic pirates. Pirates cannot capture your system or destroy your colonies, but will only steal a stockpile of resources.

After that, rush through space on your way to the center. If you get low, stop at a planet, and drop Mega Bomb's. Finally, once the system is yours, plant a colony, which 
(after it unpacks) forces the Grox out of the system, and allows you to repair.

Do so a few times and you'll have a guideline from the center back out again. Do note that once you get to the center, every single planet there will be under heavy attack. A tip someone gave, was:

> Once I'd reached the center and was working my way back out, I stopped
>   at each colony I created; repaired and refuelled then destroyed it.

Then you won't have those annoying messages anymore of the Grox attacking those planets.

EDIT: Something else I've found:

> There is a trick here, but it might be harder than the regular
>   approach.   There is a single wormhole in one of the galactic arms
>   near the Sol system  that leads very near the center of the galaxy. 
>   It's probably easier to  approach the Core and then take this wormhole
>   OUT when trying to find Sol  (instead of finding Sol and using the
>   wormhole to reach the center by taking  the wormhole IN), but either
>   way works.

And a little extra:

> When you finally reach the Galactic Core, zoom in as far as you can
>   (like  you're landing on a planet) to open an end-game cutscene.

Comment: Are you saying the Grox will keep attacking your colonies until either you ally with or destroy them? Also, is there a limit to the distance at which they can attack your colonies? It would also be nice to know where this Sol-Core wormhole is or what it's called, as my homeworld is within spitting distance of Sol.

Comment: I found this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQCC_9GJRII Do mind that the names of the stuff might be different, so watch the locations carefully. And it has been quite some time I've played the game, so I'm not too sure of it all anymore.

Comment: It seems never stopping in a system near the Grox doesn't stop them noticing you anymore - I've tried several times and they spotted me immediately.

Comment: @kotekzot Be carefull tho, the wormhole will plant you in the middle of Grox teritory, and there are alot of them.

Comment: You will always stay at war with the Grox. Always. So there is no point in trying worrying about allying with them or making peace. There isn't any way to do so.

Comment: Actually, you can create an alliance with the Grox. Doing so will result in every single other race in the universe having -200 points towards you, thus you are in war with everything but the Grox.

Answer (score 1):

I am making peace with the Grox right now. I am a Zealot, so it is easier for me, but Planet Busters also break the Galactic Code. Break the Galactic Code, do missions, and gifts will just barely allow you to reach the blue face level. It is faster if you have the greeting super power that gives an initial +10. After blue face, I am making trade routes. This will add more points to the relationship. I have not tried Super Happy Ray nor Embassy yet, but I am hoping these also may help.
The nearby empires do get upset with me, but I just use Fanatical Frenzy on home-planets and Mega-Bombs to take over their colonies and you can't have war with a nonexistent empire.